# JQUERY Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: # on javascript: void(0)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap 3 and ever since I started using jQuery 3.4.1 I have been getting this error in console:

***Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #***

This is the offending element.

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" 
  id="status-button">
          Nuevo <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li><a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="changeStatus(1)">Nuevo</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="changeStatus(2)">En progreso</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="changeStatus(3)">Completado</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="changeStatus(4)">En espera</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="changeStatus(5)">Cancelado</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
<input type="hidden" id="taskid" value="15" />
```

Strangely I couldn't find the referenced changeStatus function anywhere in the code.
I'm very new to jQuery and JS and don't know how to solve this, so if possible give me a hint.

EDIT: I'm dumb. I wasnt looking in the proper folder. Here is the code

```
function changeStatus(id) {
$('#status-button-update').fadeIn(100);
var taskid = $('#taskid').val();
$.ajax({
    url: global_base_url + "tasks/change_status",
    type: "GET",
    data: {
        status : id,
        taskid : taskid
    },
    dataType : 'json',
    success: function(msg) {
        if(msg.error) {
            alert(msg.error_msg);
            return;
        }
        if(id == 1) {
            $('#status-button').removeClass();
            $('#status-button').addClass("btn btn-info btn-xs dropdown-toggle");
            $('#status-button').html('New  <span class="caret"></span>');
        } else if(id == 2) {
            $('#status-button').removeClass();
            $('#status-button').addClass("btn btn-primary btn-xs dropdown-toggle");
            $('#status-button').html('In Progress  <span class="caret"></span>');
        } else if(id == 3) {
            $('#status-button').removeClass();
            $('#status-button').addClass("btn btn-success btn-xs dropdown-toggle");
            $('#status-button').html('Completed  <span class="caret"></span>');
        } else if(id == 4) {
            $('#status-button').removeClass();
            $('#status-button').addClass("btn btn-warning btn-xs dropdown-toggle");
            $('#status-button').html('On Hold  <span class="caret"></span>');
        } else if(id == 5) {
            $('#status-button').removeClass();
            $('#status-button').addClass("btn btn-danger btn-xs dropdown-toggle");
            $('#status-button').html('Cancelled <span class="caret"></span>');
        }
        //$('#status-button-update').html(msg);
        $('#status-button-update').fadeOut(500);
    }
})
```

Comment: for better understanding post your full code, at least jquery

Comment: For clarification, your question title doesn't match the bolded error message you put in the question.  What exactly is the error?

Comment: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #. I just put javascript: void(0) as reference because thats what I expected to be causing the error, but changing it to href="#" didn't seem to solve the issue.

Comment: With your current information, it is not possible to suggest anything

Comment: I just solved it by downgrading to jquery 2.2.4. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by downgrading to jquery 2.2.4